# Rename [gears-of-war-5] to [gears-5]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-rename-request

There are a few [gears-of-war-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-of-war-5) questions posted, and  there was one [gears-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-5) question, but I think it may have been deleted and the tag died off.

The game is officially called "Gears 5" as indicated by the [official website](https://www.gears5.com/), and as such I believe the tag should be that as well. Perhaps have a synonym made so that [gears-of-war-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-of-war-5) converts to [gears-5](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gears-5).